# Searching image for main class?

Tags: java, windows, swing, class, program-entry-point

I'm just starting to use swing in java, and I've come across a weird problem. I'm trying to add a splash screen (http://wiki.netbeans.org/Splash_Screen_Beginner_Tutorial), and everything works fine until I add `splash:src/Splash.png` to my VM options. Once I do that, I get this error:

`Error: Could not find or load main class splash:src.splash.png
Java Result: 1`

It's as if java is trying to find my main class inside the png file??? I believe my file is in the correct place, this is what it looks like:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Kv8GIsP.png]

And my main.java is just a default swing frame form. Any clue whats going on?

Thanks!

Edit: New file layout:

[image]

Changed manifest and VM settings, same error: `Error: Could not find or load main class splash:images.splash.png
Java Result: 1`

Comment: `" I believe my file is in the correct place, ..."` -- best to assume that it's not and then prove that it's in the correct place.

Comment: In the image I posted, that shows that it's in the correct place, right?

Comment: How are you running (or trying to run) the application?  My guess is you've missed the - from the VM parameter, which should read `-splash:src.splash.png`.

Comment: @NickHolt by pressing the play button in netbeans

Comment: Sorry, that should read `-splash:splash.png`

Comment: Bingo, the missing hyphen was the problem. If you make an answer, Ill vote it best answer. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't even know that you had an image, since my fire-wall blocked it for me. @Nick's your man it seems. 1+ to him and your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the error you've listed, it looks like you've missed the `-` from the `splash` vm option.  This means the command line will be:

```
java splash:src.splash.png Main.class
```

Means the Java executable thinks you're asking it to run `splash:src.splash.png`.

The command line should be (note, you don't need to include the `src` directory):

```
java -splash:images/splash.png Main.class
```

Check your VM Options in Netbeans and correct it to `-splash:images/splash.png`.

Comment: it compiles, but theres no splash when I use `-splash:splash.png`. I need to use `-splash:images/splash.png`. Thanks!!

Comment: Yes, after you move the image to another directory you'll need that - I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you puting files other than `.java` (source files) in another directory. In the most common case `src` is where Java IDEs (at least Eclipse and NetBeans) put the source files, it is pretty much standard, and the hierarchy of the folder inside it has to match your Java packages names. So, move the image to another folder, let's say `img` and try again.

Comment: That's largely irrelevant when the program runs as both the class and the png will be on the classpath.

Comment: I did as you said, but the problem continued. Still good to follow proper standards though, I suppose